# Cannot Debug Unmanaged Dll from C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, breakpoints

I have a DLL that was written in `C++` and called from a `C#` application. The `DLL` is unmanaged code.

If I copy the `DLL` and its `.pdb` files with a post build event to the `C#` app's debug execution `dir` I still can't hit any break points I put into the `DLL` code. The break point has a message attached to it saying that "no symbols have been loaded for this document".

What else do I have to do to get the debugging in the `dll` source?

I have "`Tools`->`Options`->`Debugging`->`General`->`Enable` only my code" Disabled.
The `DLL` is being compiled with "Runtime tracking and disable optimizations (/ASSEMBLYDEBUG)" and Generate Debug Info to "Yes (/DEBUG)"

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To debug into your C++ DLL you need to enable mixed mode debugging on the startup application in your solution.

- Right click on project -> Properties
- Go to Debug Tab
- Check "Enable unmanaged code debugging"

This will allow you to debug into native code for an F5 style scenario.  If you want to enable it for attaching to the process then do the following in the "Attach to Process" Dialog

- Select the process to debug
- Click on the "Select ..." button above the process list
- Click "Debug these code types"
- Check both Managed and Native

Comment: While I was going to answer this, I wasn't sure if it was so simple or not. If it is this simple, I've likely always misused it while attempting to debug managed C++ code that interfaces with native code.

Comment: Note that if your startup project uses another C# DLL project that actually calls the C++ DLL, the startup project must also have "Enable unmanaged code debugging" turned on.

Comment: Select solution in Solution Explorer. Select from >Menu|Tools|options|Debugging|General and  Uncheck "Require source files to exactly match the original version"

Comment: This is great when you have the source code of the C# app as well. But what happens if you have the source for the C++ DLL but not the C# app, for example a client using your DLL complains that it's not working, but won't give you access to the source code of their C# program? Is there a way to enable debugging then?

Comment: For VS 2013, the setting is now called "Enable native code debugging", still in the Debug tab of the project properties.

Comment: Also don't forget:  `Tool | Options | Debugging | General` at the bottom ensure that "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" is checked.

Comment: A hard to find answer couldn't get simplier. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable unmanaged (Native) debugging.

**If you are attaching to the process after it is started:**

Go to the Tools menu, and then attach to process, make sure you have native debugging enabled.

You will see a read only edit box:

> Attach to: Managed code, Native code
>   [Select]

Make sure Native code is listed there.  If not add it.

**If you are starting your project from within visual studio:**

On your project properties that you are starting in debug mode.  Go to the project Properties, and then select the debug tab.

Make sure this checkbox is checked on:

> Enable unmanaged code debugging

Answer (score 1):

When you attach to a process to debug, you have to specify how you want to attach.  You have a few options, namely Managed, and Native.  In order to debug C# code with unmanaged C++, you have to attach to a process as Managed and as Native (both can be selected at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

Had faced the same issue and did all that was suggested in the accepted answer but the breakpoints in the unmanaged DLL was not getting hit!

However, when i did the following i could finally debug the DLL!

Select solution in Solution Explorer
Select from `Menu`>>`Tools`>>`options`>>`Debugging`>>`General`
Uncheck "*Require source files to exactly match the original version*"