# Debugging .NET Core App in Docker - attaching to unmanaged code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, docker, debugging, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.0 application that I run in Linux docker container in Visual Studio 2019 using Docker Support. I can debug .NET Core code just fine. But I've got an unmanaged .so library (c++) loaded with the app that I need to debug. When I open "Attach to process" dialog in Visual Studio I can see that it only allows attaching to managed code in Docker.

Are there any ways for me to debug that unmanaged library?

Comment: Try to debug in the mixed mode, here is more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744888/cannot-debug-unmanaged-dll-from-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks, but the question you mentioned talks about VS 2008, and does not seem to be valid for my scenario